# Selecting distinct Vals

Tags: sql, ssms, distinct, proc-sql

So I have three columns for this data table (Table1). Namely, a ParentId column, a ChildId column, and a IsNew column.

ParentId refers to the Entity's parent ID. Each parentId has multiple child Ids so combining a parentId and a child Id gives a unique entityId. ChildId refers to the entity's childId.

For example, parent 0001 can have two children 0001, and 0002. There unique entityId's are 00010001, and 00010002.

I'm trying to return a list of all distinct ParentIds that ONLY HAVE the value "Yes" for the IsNew column for all its childIds. For example, ParentId 54 would work because both of its children (2 and 4) have values of "Yes". However, ParentId 14 would not work because it has a "Yes" for childId 2 but a "No" for childIDs 3 and 4.

The code I have now is the following which isn't working:

[I am using SAS by the way and using procsql while connected to SSMS]

```
proc sql; select distinct ParentId from Table1 where IsNew = 'Yes' and IsNew != 'No'; run;
```

Any help would be appreciated. [Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIWVm.png)

Comment: Remove the `distinct` clause

Comment: What do you think the exclamation point is doing in that code?  You can use `!!` as a substitute for the concatenation operator `||`, but you cannot use `!` as a substitute for the not symbol.  Either use the actual not symbol on an EBCIDIC machine or use `~` or `^` character on an ASCII machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql; 
select distinct ParentId 
from Table1 
where ParentId not in (select ParentId from Table1 where isNew is null or IsNew = 'No');
run;
```

I added logic to also not include parentId where isNew is null although I do not know if that is possible (and not enough karma to write comments)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you! I did not know you can have a select statement within another select statement.

Comment: That is called a subquery and it is very useful!